# Select row query given table name and primary key in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So after googling this simple question, I could have not find an answer anywhere. I only have very basic database knowledge, and I need a query in Oracle to properly select a row given a table name and a primary key. Most examples I have found all find rows based of a row number or rowID (is that the same as primary key?).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried, some data, etc... ?!

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the primary key column and the value you want to query? Where or what exactly did you search for? This is a very basic SELECT statement in any relational database:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE primary_key_column = primary_key_value
```

Unless, of course, I didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

A primary key is a unique identifier for a row in a table. Each row will have a primary key that is different from all other rows. This key can be one value, such as a rowID, or it can be a composite value (multiple columns used as a primary key because there may not be a need for an extra column only to store a rowID).

@tilley31 above shows a great example of how to search for a specific row in a table. If the primary key was composite;

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE primary_key_column1 = primary_key_value1
AND primary_key_column2 = primary_key_value2
```

Answer (score 0):

ROWID is a pseudocolumn that returns the address of a row and is usually unique, exception being where more than one table is stored in a same cluster then those tables rows can share the same rowid. ROWID is implicitly given by the oracle to rows.

Primary key uniquely identifies a row at a table level and is created by the user who created the table.

*Getting the ROWID of a Row*

```
SELECT ROWID,FIELDNAME FROM ABC;
```

*Getting the PRIMARY Key of a table*

```
SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLENAME'
AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='P';
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are intent to dynamically choose table and where clauses in query (?) 
If this is what you want to do then answer is No. Its not possible just through query. You could achieve it through pl/sql. and if you must have this as a query consider using a table function like below -

SELECT * FROM TABLE(func('TABLE_NAME','WHERE_CONDITION'))

Check out this link: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

Again this requires you to have preset output columns (COLUMN1, COLUMN2 etc). You will not be able to select exact column names from table.

Overall this is going to be messy.